# How can I optimize webpack bundle commons.[hash].js on nextjs project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-router, next.js

[image: Bundle commons.[hash].js chunk]

So I have this result from webpack-bundle-analyzer. As you can see I have this chunk commons.[hash].js with huge size (3 MB). It consists of all node_modules, components, redux, actions, helpers, hocs, ...etc. And all pages chunk are looking good (at least that's what I think).

Can someone please explain to me how this works? and How can I optimize the commons.[hash].js chunk? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think next js build is already optimized for static content. Even I tried to find but couldn't find a way to optimize more.

Comment: Next already optimizes the commons file. One thing you can do to decrease the size of the bundle is selectively remove unwanted modules.
e.g. I always remove locale from moment.
You use the IgnurePlugin module to this.
`config.plugins.push(new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/));
`

Comment: I thought the same too, next js already optimized.

@lakshman.pasala Thank you for the suggestion, but I've already done that.

But about the commons.[hash].js file, it consists a lot of components, I think its already includes in all the pages that needed them right? isn't that gonna be redundant then? CMIIW

Comment: @HansonCitra can you share your example next.config.js after that improvements?